# How to dynamically populate multi column of a div in html?

Tags: html

Based on the content available in 'div',i want to divide and show it in no.of columns .please tell me how to acheive this?

any samples please tell me know.

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        tab_Div = $('#id_of_table');
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            debugger;
            $('<tr>').appendTo(tab_Div);
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                $('<td>'+ j + '</td>').appendTo(tab_Div);
            }
            $('</tr>').appendTo(tab_Div);
        }
```

Comment: How you want to divde? on which condition?  `" "`, `,`,`_`,`|`?

Comment: if 180items are there in div divide it as 3 columns each row should have 60 elements like that need to divide the div.extra item added 181 it should be display under first coulmn.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the data in the div. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: like the above i tried but no use?please correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/eF2BF/3/

The answer depends on how your data is structured in the div, and if you want the first 60 items to be the first column, the 60 next to be the second, etc.
The simplest way to do it is to alternate between the columns, in this fashion:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
Item 0   | Item 1   | Item 2
Item 3   | Item 4   | Item 5
```

I have provided a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eF2BF/3/
Where the main part of the code is this bit:

```
//Loop through each row (60 times)
for (i = numItems * j; i < numItems * numColumns; i = i + numColumns) {
    tableHtml += '<tr>';
    //Loop through al each column (3 times)
    for (j = 0; j < numColumns; j = j + 1) {
        index = i + j;
        tableHtml += '<td>' + $($items[index]).text() + '</td>'
    }
    tableHtml += '</tr>';

}
```

## Edit

I updated the fiddle with a second solution to get Items 0-59 in the first column, 60-119 in the second, etc. You can find it at the bottom:

```
//SOLUTION 2
tableHtml = '<table>';
for (i = 0; i < numItems; i = i + 1) {

    tableHtml += '<tr>';

    for(j = 0; j < numColumns; j = j+1){
        tableHtml += '<td>' + $($items[i + (j * numItems)]).text() + '</td>';
    }
    tableHtml += '</tr>';

}
tableHtml += '</table>';

$("#table2").html(tableHtml);
```